# Playing audio in IDEA works but when compiled into a jar it errors

Tags: java, audio

When running this in IntelliJ IDEA it works fine, audio plays however when I build this as an artifact it errors on

```
play.close();
```

This is the stacktrace

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: line already closed
>       at org.classpath.icedtea.pulseaudio.PulseAudioClip.close(PulseAudioClip.java:241)
>       at me.com.test.main.playAudio(main.java:37)
>       at me.com.test.main.main(main.java:50)

```
public static Boolean playAudio(File localSoundURL) {
    Clip play = null;
    try {
        AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(localSoundURL);
        play = AudioSystem.getClip();
        play.open(audioInputStream);

        FloatControl volume = (FloatControl) play.getControl(FloatControl.Type.MASTER_GAIN);
        volume.setValue(6.0f);

        play.start();
        play.drain();
    } catch(UnsupportedAudioFileException |IOException | LineUnavailableException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    } finally {
        try {
            assert play != null;
            play.close();
        } catch (Exception exp) {
            exp.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            return true;
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    System.out.println(playAudio(new File(FileSystemView.getFileSystemView().getHomeDirectory()+"/Music/tahdah.wav")));
}
```

Comment: Have you tried putting tadah.wav into the project dir, and then have it packaged into the jar and just call playAudio(newFile("tadah.wav"))

Comment: @user2277872 Same error unfortunately.